# Binding Label to a static string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, label

I have made a Base Form which is inherited by most Forms in the application. Base form contains a Status Bar Control that displays user name which is internally a static string.
 User can `Switch User` at any point in the application by pressing a button on status bar. At this point the user name in the status bar should also change, as if now it only changes in code and UI has no idea about the change. I have googled around and found that i need to bind the label with that static string by implementing a INotifyProperty Interface. I have implemented many example code without success.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must implement a class to notify prop changed and therefore the prop can not be static. Combine with a singleton pattern and you have yout solution.

```
public class Global : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _userName;

    public string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._userName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._userName == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            this._userName = value;

            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("UserName"));
            }
        {
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Global() {}

    public static readonly Global Get = new Global();
}
```

Usage:

```
var currUserName = Global.Get.UserName;

Global.Get.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.PropertyName);
Global.Get.UserName = "John";
```

And bind to Global.Get to property UserName.

Answer (score 1):

use BindableAttribute for the property you want to bind a control to it.

```
[Bindable(true)]
public int Username {
   get {
       // Insert code here.
       return 0;
   }
   set {
      // Insert code here.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would:

1- Add a timer to the base form to update the status bar. (the timer resolution is uo to your requirement).

the timer Tick handler would be something like this:

```
private void timerStatusUpdate_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolStripStatusLabelMessage.Text = StatusMessage();
}
```

2 - Add a virtual StatusMessage method to your base class:

```
class BaseForm : Form
{
    .......

    public virtual string StatusMessage()
    {
        return "override me!";
    }
}
```

3- override StatusMessage in all your derived classes

```
class XXXForm : BaseForm
{
    ........

    public override string StatusMessage()
    {
        return "XXXForm status message";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Reactive Extensions for these things

For example if you have a Context class with a property UserName

you could do this

```
public static class Context
{
   public static Subject<string> UserChanged = new Subject<string>();

   private static string user;
   public static string User
   {
      get { return user; }
      set
      {
         if (user != value)
         {
            user = value;

            UserChanged.OnNext(user);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And then on your forms just do

```
   Context.UserChanged.ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
                      .Subscribe(user => label.Text = user);
```

The ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current) makes it safe for cross thread operation calls

Comment: what is this OnNext ?